# neo4j cypher inserting a new node does not carry over the existing relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am extremely new to neo4j cypher query language. I have created a simplistic graph between nodes Client -> Portfolio -> Trade. Here are the cypher statements:

```
create (c:Client {id:1, name:"Yezdi"}) return c;
create (p:Portfolio {id:1, name:"Yezdi-1", cId:1}) return p;
create (p:Portfolio {id:2, name:"Yezdi-2", cId:1}) return p;
create (p:Portfolio {id:3, name:"Yezdi-3", cId:1}) return p;
create (t:Trade {id:1, qty:100, prc:23.44, pId:1}) return t;
create (t:Trade {id:2, qty:102, prc:23.44, pId:1}) return t;
create (t:Trade {id:3, qty:103, prc:23.44, pId:1}) return t;
create (t:Trade {id:4, qty:104, prc:23.44, pId:2}) return t;
create (t:Trade {id:5, qty:105, prc:23.44, pId:3}) return t;
create (t:Trade {id:6, qty:106, prc:23.44, pId:3}) return t;

match (c:Client),(p:Portfolio) where c.id=p.cId create unique (c)-[:HAS_PORT]->(p);
match (p:Portfolio), (t:Trade) where p.id = t.pId create unique (p)-[:HAS_TRADE]->(t)
```

When i added the 7th Trade node

```
create (t:Trade {id:7, qty:107, prc:23.44, pId:2}) return t;
```

it did not connect itself to "Yezdi-2" portfolio. 
What am i missing. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for higher volumes you want to split it up.

I don't think you need the id's when the other identifiers/names are enough.

1. Create index / constraints per client, portfolio, trade separately
2. Create clients separately.
3. Create portfolios and connection to client
4. pass in a collection of trades, use FOREACH to create the trades and connect them to client and portfolios

#### Create client

```
create (c:Client {name:{name}})
```

#### Create Portfolio

```
MATCH (c:Client {name:{name}})
FOREACH (p in {portfolios} |
  MERGE (c)-[:HAS_PORT]->(:Portfolio {name:p.name})
```

#### Create Trades

```
FOREACH (t in {trades} |
  MERGE (p:Portfolio {name: t.portfolio})
  MERGE (p)-[:HAS_TRADE]->(:Trade {qty:t.quantity, prc:t.price})
)
```

**And use parameters in cypher against the server or embedded API**

Comment: @Yezidi123: Can you try this and comment on its performance versus the suggestion below? It'd make a great case study.

Comment: @Michael: I tried your solution itself. That's why you have a tick against your answer :-). Forget about creating relations, i was just inserting 30000 clients using Neo4JClient and it takes about ~4 secs. Creating 50000 portfolios for those 30000 clients using relations takes forever. There has to be some config that i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at MERGE instead of CREATE UNIQUE since you're using Cypher 2.

Anyway, if you added the 7th trade note AFTER you ran those two CREATE UNIQUE statements above, you're going to have to re-run that second CREATE UNIQUE statement (again, though, since you're blanketing everything in that MATCH, try changing CREATE UNIQUE to MERGE).  MERGE will be sure to only create a node/relationship if it doesn't already exist (i.e. none can be matched in the MERGE pattern).

Also, it looks as though you're creating things in a very RDBMS kind of style, which is a habit you should try to get out of.  It's ok to specify nodes and relationships at creation time, e.g.

```
MERGE (c:Client {name: "Yezdi"})-[:HAS_PORT]->(p:Portfolio {name: "Yezdi-2"};
MERGE (t:Trade {qty:107, prc:23.44})<-[:HAS_TRADE]-(p);
MERGE (t:Trade {qty:100, prc:23.44})<-[:HAS_TRADE]-(p);
...
```

Try not to worry so much about "joins" in the RDBMS sense.  You likely don't need to worry too much about the individual node IDs, unless there's an external purpose in your code for some reason (and even, I wouldn't worry too much).

HTH

Comment: thanks @HTH for replying. I was hoping that i dont have to rerun that relation again. In a trade system where we can have 1000 trades pumped into the DB in a sec, rerunning the relation query doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: Which is probably why it's best to create (i.e. merge) the node and relationship at the same time as they come in.  If you're in a high-write load situation, you'll have several other considerations to look at including Memory Mapped IO and other tuning mechanisms (especially if you're on a Linux box). Batch insertion might be another possibility unless you have a near-real time requirement.

Comment: Thanks again, but thats just one relation, a node can have a lot of relations and refresh all in near-real time scenario is scary, may be i would have to just try it out and see. Will update this post with the results.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're missing the point or if I am, but, I'm saying it's best to create the relationships WHEN you create the new nodes, so you don't have to "refresh".

Comment: I was missing the point here ... you were right i was thinking from a RDBMS point of view. Having said that the performance is slow. It takes about 5 secs to insert 30,000 Clients. I am sure that i am missing some config. Using it out of the box from the install and running on my PC (64-bit, 8 GB ram, 8 CPU i7-3770 @ 3.4 GHz). Thanks  again.